# Proving isomorphism for commutative ring for which $1 + 1 \in R^* $

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Having a commutative ring $R$ for which $1 + 1 \in R^\times$, I want to prove that $$ R[X] / (X^2 - 1)  \cong R\times R.$$

I've tried some juggling with the first isomorphism theorem for rings and rewriting, but not sure how to solve this. I've used the definition of an ideal to prove that $(X^2-1)$ is one.

Comment: $R^\times$ or $U(R)$ are the standard notations for the group of units of $R$.

Answer (score 1):

I abbreviate $2=1+1$. The assumption means that we are allowed to divide things by two.

Leaving you with a ton of details to check. The following is a roadmap for solving this.

1. Consider the mapping $f:R[X]\to R\times R$ given by $f(p(X))=(p(1),p(-1))$. Show that it is a homomorphism of rings.
2. Show that $f((1+X)/2)=(1,0)$ and $f((1-X)/2)=(0,1)$. Conclude that $f$ is surjective.
3. Show that $X^2-1$, and hence all of the ideal $(X^2-1)$ is contained in the kernel of $f$.
4. Show that the only linear polynomial $p(X)=aX+b$ in the kernel has $a=b=0$ (you need invertibility of $2$ for this).
5. Show that any polynomial $p(X)$ in the kernel of $f$ is actually in the ideal $(X^2-1)$. Hint: You need polynomial long division by $X^2-1$ here. Then apply the previous step.
6. Apply the first isomorphism theorem.

---

This is not at all unlike doing decompositions like $\Bbb{Z}_6\simeq \Bbb{Z}_3\times\Bbb{Z}_2$, $\Bbb{Z}_{15}\simeq\Bbb{Z}_5\times\Bbb{Z}_3$. Instead of the coprime integers $2,3$ (resp. $3,5$) we use the coprime polynomials $(X-1)$ and $(X+1)$. In other words, this is an instance of *the Chinese Remainder Theorem*.
Only this time both components $R[X]/(X+1)$ and $R[X]/(X-1)$ are isomorphic to $R$.